# Triple Monitor Stand Recommendations

Tags: multiple-monitors, portrait

I've got two Acer X233Hbid 23" Widescreen LCD Monitors from new egg back last summer, each weigh 10.5lbs a piece

I want to buy a third Acer 23" (closest I've found is the X235 on Newegg, weighs in at 11.5 lbs), one of the new ATI video cards that will output to 3 displays, and then a monitor stand that will let me use them in portrait mode like the image below.

[image]

I found the following: $260 - ERGOTRON 33-323-200 DS100 Triple-Monitor Desk Stand 
and was wondering if anyone has any experience with this kind of setup and whether it would work for me or not...

Comment: Out of curiousity, do you plan on just having an awesome amount of work space or is there some software/games that utilize this 3 way portrait setup well?

Comment: The above image is from a review about ATI's new Eyefinity tech, which if I understand correctly, should work with all games. 

I don't game much right now, but I seem to never have enough work space available.  I got the dual arms I mentioned below and currently have my 23's in portrait mode so it is like the picture above, but with only two lcd's. I already love the extra vertical space which makes reading long web pages/PDF's a snap. 

I'm sure I'll get back into games one of these days, and at that point the massive display will definitely be nice (and i'll probably get that 3rd lcd then)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't have an answer as per the tripple monitor mount, but I finally went with one of the ERGOTRON LX Dual Desk Mount Arm since I currently only have 2 LCD's.  Whenever I get around to getting a 3rd, I'll probably just get another Ergotron since the ones I have now work so well.

Jeff Atwood convinced me with his post here: [LCD Monitor Arms](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/lcd-monitor-arms.html)